# Heir to Bharata, son of Dhushyanta

Tags: mahabharata, bharata

In [this passage](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01095.htm) of Mahabharata, it says Bharata's sons were slayed, and he got another son through sacrifice.

> Bharata begat upon his three wives nine sons in all. But none of them were like their father and so Bharata was not at all pleased with them. Their mothers, therefore, became angry and slew them all. The procreation of children by Bharata, therefore, became vain. The monarch then performed a great sacrifice and through the grace of Bharadwaja obtained a son named Bhumanyu.

The TV serial on Mahabharata depicted that Bharata handed over the kingdom to the son of his general because he didn't consider his own sons to worthy.

So, the link above is a translation error or is it the TV serial is incorrect? Any other references on this please? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same story which is quoted in question is also mentioned in [Vishnu Purana, Book 4, Chapter 19](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp112.htm). In this story, nine sons of Bharata were killed by their mothers.

> Bharata had by different wives nine sons, but they were put to death by their own mothers, because Bharata remarked that they bore no resemblance to him, and the women were afraid that he would therefore desert them.

Comment: @triyugi-Narayana-Mani: thank you. that cruel of a father who we got so much respect for!!

Comment: @SHebbar If you're satisfied with this answer, you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark (✓) below the voting buttons. if you like it you may press the up arrow for voting. That’s how the site knows whether the answer is satisfactory and answers the question askers questions :)